# How to split / replace different values in same column Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, text, calculated-columns

I have a column i.e. `p_author` in sql server table named as `sub_aminer_paper` containing values of single or multiple authors having data type `text` separated by semi-colons i.e. `;`
Now I have to assign the respective id's to this column values i.e. `p_author` where id's for these authors are stored in another table named `sub_aminer_author` in the column `aid`.
The view of both tables are attached as images.
Table `sub_aminer_author`

[image]

Table `sub_aminer_paper`

[image]

I have highlighted `aid` and `name` columns in `sub_aminer_author` table and `p_author` column in `sub_aminer_paper` table.

Now I have to add a new column named `p_authors_id`in `sub_aminer_paper` table and fill it with respective `aid` from `sub_aminer_author` table.

I am attaching the sample data in csv format for both table (only concerned columns data)

Here are the links to csv files

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ihKgOLimL0MUhHZFlpLThTZzA/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ihKgOLimL0cEtyYVR0WExBbFk/view?usp=sharing)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ihKgOLimL0MUhHZFlpLThTZzA/view?usp=sharing

And for the table creation, here is the code --
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sub_aminer_paper](
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [p_author] [varchar](max) NULL)`

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sub_aminer_author](
    [aid] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](max) NULL)`

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: How the tables are related?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas as there is no key relation between tables but the values for column **name** in table `sub_aminer_author` are identical to values for column **p_author** in table `sub_aminer_paper`

Comment: Will the new column `p_authors_id` be delimited by semicolon `;` too?

Comment: If at all possible you should consider normalizing your `sub_aminer_paper` table and stop storing multiple discrete values in a single column. Adding yet another column holding delimited data would just make a bad design even worse. What you should to is to add a third table that models the PaperAuthor relation like (pid, aid)

Comment: @FelixPamittan delimited by `;` or `,` both fine

Comment: @jpw I have this database imported from a data set, not created my own

Comment: AS @jpw pointed out, this is a bad idea.

Comment: @FelixPamittan its fine idea is not good, but I have the data in same form because I'm not designing or creating data myself, I have a data set to use in my work so have to manipulate the same

Answer (score 0):

This will split the semi-colon `;` delimited values and then join it to the Authors table to get the AID from authors table.

-- Add a new column to sub_aminer_paper table

```
ALTER TABLE sub_aminer_paper
 ADD AID VARCHAR(100)
GO
```

-- Update statement

```
WITH X AS 
 (
    SELECT *
    FROM
     (
        SELECT  PID
               ,Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') p_Author
        FROM   
       (SELECT PID
            ,Cast ('<X>' + Replace(p_Author, ';', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
           FROM    sub_aminer_paper
          ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
     ) t 
     INNER JOIN sub_aminer_author t1 ON t.p_Author = t1.Name
 ), Y AS
  (
    SELECT * 
          ,STUFF((SELECT ';' + CAST(AID AS VARCHAR(20))
                  FROM X 
                  WHERE X.pid = Y.pid
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                  .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')  NewAID   
    FROM X AS Y
 )
 UPDATE t
  SET AID = Y.NewAID
FROM sub_aminer_paper t
INNER JOIN Y ON Y.pid = t.pid
```

**Important Note**

Do yourself a favour and normalize your data, this query could have been so simpler if your data was normalized. I have tried to put a lipstick on a pig but its still a pig.

Comment: @M.Ali--will you explain your answer that how it works? Or you tried this query on your own behalf? I can't understand this query

Comment: @maliks, how can he try it without sample data? Please post your sample data in a consumable format i.e `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but I am 99.9% sure it will work :)

Comment: @M.Ali have you got my question? If yes, please explain your answer what will be the output in newly created column i.e. `p_authors_id`?

Comment: @FelixPamittan I have shown the sample data in image format and table names are also depicted here

Comment: @M.Ali ok let me check, and please I have also uploaded the sample data and table creation, you can check out yourself for surety. Thanks

Comment: @M.Ali this query not working, please check yourself as I have provided the sample data